# How to calculate the distance between points?

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate the distance between the user locations, access points and base station

```
figure('Color', 'white')
UserLocationX = randi(50, 1, 50);  
UserLocationY = randi(50, 1, 50);
plot(UserLocationX, UserLocationY, '^-', 'MarkerSize', 5, 'LineWidth', 2), hold on    
AccessPointX = randi(50, 1, 8);
AccessPointY = randi(50, 1, 8);
plot(AccessPointX, AccessPointY, 'go', 'MarkerSize', 5, 'LineWidth', 6), hold on
BaseStationX = 25;
BaseStationY = 25;
plot(BaseStationX, BaseStationY, 'rs', 'MarkerSize', 5, 'LineWidth', 6), hold on, grid on
leg = legend('User Location', 'Access Point', 'Base Station');  
set(leg, 'Location', 'NorthEastOutside')
xlabel('x-candidate')
ylabel('y-candidate')
title('Scenario')
```

Comment: Between users and BS, between BS and AP, or between users and AP?

Comment: Between users and BS, between user and AP

Comment: I changed the title. "How to write Matlab Code" was quite broad ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/pdist2.html).

Between AP and users:

```
pdist2([AccessPointX(:) AccessPointY(:)],[UserLocationX(:) UserLocationY(:)])
```

Other cases are similar.

Comment: The distance did not show in Figure

Comment: This is the answer to your question ("to calculate the distance"). If this is not what you want, I suggest to rephrase your question.